# client, account and transactions, how to design it in a microservices approach?

Tags: rest, microservices, software-design

I am designing a solution and would like to double check if this is according to the microservices architecture.

We have clients, accounts and transactions like a normal bank account.
Clients have basic data like name and address.
Accounts might be for savings or current
Transactions are money transfers between 2 accounts

So I am designing the following way:

1 microservice to manage client data (will manage just client basic data and their addresses)

1 microservice to manage account data (will manage account basic, the client id is part of the account data)

1 microservice to manage money data (will have the account's balance and all transfers)

Please let me know if this is according to the microservice architecture and if you have another understanding.

Comment: As long as these services can operate independently and scale , you should be good. there is no right answer in microservices architecture but good practices. From top level i don't see a problem unless you have specific concern.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, the main goal of a microservices architecture is to support faster and continuous releases of different parts of a big system without waiting on each other. There are two approaches to design a new system, microservices first approach and microservices later approach. In the first approach, the system is designed from ground up to follow microservices architecture, the system is initially itself broken down into services and the services talk to each other typically over HTTP & REST. In the other approach, system is initially is not built as microservices and all the modules are under single application. Both of these approaches has it pros and cons which is a separate discussion.

In your case, you are taking the first approach, to design the new system with separate services for each functionality. I am not an expert in banking domain but from what I understand, the client (customer) system can be definitely a separate service and be responsible for maintaining customer master data. The account service can be responsible for maintaining accounts data and serve out account related information. However, account balance is an integral property of an account and it should be always associated with an account. Finally the transfer can be a separate service that can record the transfers between accounts. Whenever there is a transfer, it can query the accounts for their current balance and if the transfer is valid one, then it can record the transfer.

However as this involves financial transaction, you would have to make sure that each transaction follows the ACID rules. Maintaining ACID properties among distributed systems is tricky and there are several ways to mitigate this such as only having ACID transactions on the most critical areas and having eventual consistency on the others. For example, banks do not immediately reflect all the transactions to the customer as "completed" and instead show the message saying "pending to be processed" (eventual consistency) so that customer is aware of the exact status.